# collapsible table windows form control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm new to .NET and windows programming.

Does anyone know if there's a collapsible table control that looks like the properties window in visual studio?

exmaple:
http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC67543.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be WinForms [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control?

Comment: Not maybe, it *is* the property grid control :)

Comment: @Hans, I've added "may be" due to 30 chars limit of the message length. Undoubtful, it's it, thank you.